# Import level(s): singular or plural

Tags: singular-vs-plural, singular

> The graph shows the volume of seafood imports in the US from 2000 to 2020, along with a prediction for 2030. The US seafood import market grew substantially in the past 20 years, but in the future **import levels** are expected to shrink.

The graph is only about the volume of seafood imports and only shows 4 numbers: the volume in 2000, 2010, 2020 and 2030.

Could anyone explain why "import levels" in the last sentence should be plural because there is only one forecasted number (2030)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, the meaning of "[level](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/level)" is:

> **9 :** the magnitude of a quantity considered in relation to an arbitrary reference value

With this meaning, the word can be used as either singular or plural without changing the meaning. Here's an example from the Merriam-Webster page linked above:

> And, research suggests that dragon fruit might have higher antioxidant **levels** than other tropical fruits, including mango, lychee, and papaya.
> — Erica Sweeney, Men's Health, 18 May 2023

So in your example sentence, it means exactly the same thing as "*...the import level...*"